# Declaring sourcetype in inputs.conf for a */ directory

Tags: logging, splunk

I have an inputs.conf that looks something like this:

```
[monitor:///var/www/site/shared/log/*]                              
disabled = false                                                        
followTail = 1                                                          
sourcetype=rails                                                        
crcSalt = <SOURCE>                                                      

[monitor:///var/www/site/shared/log/resque_events.log]      
disabled = false                                                        
followTail = 1                                                          
sourcetype=json_predefined_timestamp                                    
crcSalt = <SOURCE>
```

A couple questions: 
Does splunk double up indexing the `resque_events.log`? 
Is splunk smart enough to figure out that source type from the initial parsing, or do I need declare it like I did?

I'm not sure if this is redundant, I'm looking for guidance here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would avoid using `followTail`. If you don't want to index historical logs, then you should consider using `ignoreOlderThan` instead. Also `crcSalt = <SOURCE>` will cause Splunk to re-index rotated logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `inputs.conf`, the more specific monitor path will override the general one, therefore your `resque_events.log` will have the `json_predefined_timestamp` sourcetype.

If you want to see how Splunk reads your `inputs.conf`, then try the following command:

```
./splunk cmd btool inputs list --debug
```

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/inputsconf